# Codeigniter isn't applying one of the css stylesheets

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have 3 css stylesheets set to load withing the base_template in a codeigniter application.

I did not do the initial setup for the page (an undocumented page) and im basically bruteforcing every problem until it looks good enough.

The problem seems to be that the css I added, by basically changing the static base_template page, is loading, but the rules within arent being applied.

Is there more setup required for a single css file within codeigniter? Or am i going about it all wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox's firebug (an additional add in) or IE's developer tools (F12 once you're in the IE window) and "Inspect Element" on the element that does not have the style being applied to it.  You will be able to see what styles are affecting that element and see your collisions as well...

Likely if codeigniter has gen'ed a lot of the css for you, they're probably styling the elements in a less obvious way than you would have.  Firebug, Chrome's dev tools, and IE's dev tools can all help you discover what styles ARE getting applied. I tend to start there and work my way back to the css with problems like these.

Here's the link for firebug: http://getfirebug.com/html

Comment: Well thanks to firebug i actually noted the problem, but im already stuck there. And indeed even though i find "my_css.css" within the css list in the firebug app. Its present with the page being brought as link or something but codeigniter seems to be deciding to apply the rules of "another_css.css".

Comment: You should be able to right click on the element that's not rendering correctly and find out what css IS being applied... then we can work back to why your stylesheet isn't being applied...

Comment: I learned which stylesheet was being applied, and it wasnt infact the one i wanted, but what can i do with this information? Is there any more information i can give to try and zoom into the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it is because your browser cache is not updated? Either delete cache from your browser history or change the css version number like below, which will force the browser to automatically download the css file:

```
 <link href="/path/to/local/file.css?ver=1.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: The way I added the new stylesheet was by using `echo css_asset("wp_css");` Im not even sure how if this is correct for all instances, but it did work at least once already, which is the strange thing about all of this.  the stylesheet worked appropriately for one page but it isn't being applied to another whithin the same Controller context.

Comment: Ok found how to do it. but it didnt work as intended. does it matter if i appended `?ver=1.1` to every css file?

Comment: Browsers download the css file from a site and store it in cache- they read from this cache for a certain time period for future requests. However, if your css file has changed in between, the browser will not apply it as it wouldn't have downloaded it- it's still reading the cached copy. So, to force the browser to download, I suggested giving a new version number. You can give any version number that it is different from the previous css version and the browser will download it. So, you may or may not append the version number to every css file, based on this